# swipe from jquerymobile does not work in VisualForce?

Tags: visualforce, force.com, mobile, jquery

I tried swipe from jquerymobile in HTML and Javascript, it is working fine. As below

```
<html>

    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#home").swipeleft(function(){
                    $.mobile.changePage("#page1");
                });
            });
        </script>

    </head>

    <body>
<div data-role="page" id="home"> 
    <div data-role="content">
        <p>
            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c">
                <li id="listitem">Swipe Right to view Page 1</li>
            </ul>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="page1"> 
    <div data-role="content">

        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c">
            <li data-role="list-divider">Navigation</li> 
            <li><a href="#home">Back to the Home Page</a></li>
        </ul>

        <p>
            Yeah!<br />You Swiped Right to view Page 1
        </p>
    </div>
</div>

    </body>

</html>
```

But I tried the same thing in VisualForce, it does not work. As below:

```
<apex:page docType="html-5.0" standardStylesheets="false" showHeader="false" cache="true" controller="InstallerController">

    <html>

        <head>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="{!$Resource.jqueryMobileCSS}" />
        <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.jqueryJS}"/>
        <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.jqueryMobileJS}"/>
        <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.installer}"/>                       
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#mainpage").swipeleft(function(){
                    $.mobile.changePage("#page1");
                });
            });
        </script>



            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" context="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no; "/>


        </head>

        <body>
            <div data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="mainpage" >
                <div data-role="header">
                    <a href="#mainpage" id="home" class="ui-btn-left" data-icon="home">Home</a>
                    <h1>Activities</h1>
                    <a href="#" id="delete" class="ui-btn-right" data-icon="delete"></a>
                    <!--<a href="#" id="back" class="ui-btn-right" data-icon="back"></a>-->
                </div>

                <div data-role="content">
                    <ul id="activitylist" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c" data-dividertheme="b">
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="page1" >
                <div data-role="header">
                    <a href="#mainpage" id="home" class="ui-btn-left" data-icon="home">Home</a>
                    <h1>Customer Profile</h1>
                </div>
                <div data-role="content">
                    <h1>new page</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>


</apex:page>
```

I used same version of CSS,JS. It just does not work. I do not know if it is VisualForce's problem or my code's problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try using jQuery's `noConflict()` method, collisions with the `$` often cause issues:

```
var jq = jQuery.noConflict();
jq(document).ready(function(){
  jq("#mainpage").swipeleft(function(){
    jq.mobile.changePage("#page1");
  });
});
```

Other than that, check the javascript console for any errors and also ensure that all the resources are being loaded correctly (try the net tab in Chrome debugger / Firebug).

Comment: yes, you are correct,I missed this line

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that might be wrong here. You should start by opening the browser JavaScript console (Command - Option - J (Mac) or Control -Shift -J (Windows/Linux)) after the page has loaded and troubleshooting from there. If you're still stuck then post the error here.

If I were to hazard a guess I'd say that your static resources are archived bundles of files (.zip or .tar.gz). Is that correct? If so you need to read [this article](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_resources.htm) (search for "zip") to learn how to reference the files in archive.

Comment: thanks for reply. I know these two things. For static resource, I tried both. In archive or in single file. I know my import static files work because the css styles are showing on the page. Only the swipe function does not work.

Comment: And you've got no JS errors? Is the HTML that's being generated from the VF as expected?

Answer (score 0):

Jie, I use swipe successfully on a JQM page in VF.

Generally, the JQM guides recommend not binding to the ready event.  Try one of the page* events like pageshow or pageload on your mainpage

Best of luck.